# Send data from Settings Activity to Watch Face

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, wear-os

I just developed a simple Android Wear Watch Face to start learning something about Android Wear.

App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gerardcuadras.minimalflat (So simple)

The watch face change his Background color when the user taps the screen. Now, I want to add an Activity that show's a list of colors and let the user select one instead of tapping the screen.

I added this lines to my manifest that adds the config toggle to the watch face.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.wearable.watchface.wearableConfigurationAction"
android:value="com.gerardcuadras.minimalflat.wearable.watchface.CONFIG_DIGITAL" />
```

After that I created an Activity that handles the button click:

```
public void broadcastIntent(View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "broadcastIntent: Pressed button");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction("com.gerardcuadras.minimalflat.CUSTOM_INTENT");
    intent.putExtra("extra", "extra data");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Then on MyWatchFace.java (extends CanvasWatchFaceService) I have this that it supposes to handle the broadcast:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: WORKS!");
        }
    }
```

When I run the emulator and click at the button, the only thing that I see on the console is:

> "broadcastIntent: Pressed button"

So the receiver (maybe the sender) isn't working because it's not logging the **onReceive() log**.

I'm really new at Android. I'm sure I'm not doing this well or I'm missing something.

I will appreciate any help or any documentation to continue learning step by step.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to send an intent from a handheld activity to the wear device?

Comment: Are you registering a listener for that Broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better fit for using SharedPreferences (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

With SharedPreferences the selection will be persisted even if the user changes to a different watch face and back.

You can also use a registered Preference Change Listener to detect the changes made in your configuration activity.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [WearPreferenceActivity](https://github.com/denley/WearPreferenceActivity) library for your PreferencesActivity, which changes the SharedPreferences `android:key="pref_key"`. Your watch face reads preferences via `mSharedPref.getBoolean("pref_key", false);`.

One easy way to detect preference changes is, to listen to the onVisibilityChanged event, which will be called after the PreferencesActivity gets closed.